# Why is all audio suddenly phase cancelling on headphones?

Tags: audio

When I listen to audio through headphones on my Galaxy S2, there's a phase-cancellation effect that attenuates any centered signal (so I often get most of the music but little of the vocal, or on podcasts with voices panned center I get very little anything).

But if I listen in the car - through a 3.5mm male-to-male aux cable -  or on the internal speaker, the audio sounds fine.

I've tried four sets of headphones, with both two and three contact jacks.

Also tried hard-resetting the phone, and this didn't have any effect.

All these headphones *used to* work fine. I started having this issue earlier this week, around 2/28.